# Show cross tab Headers in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on crystal reports.

I have used a cross tab in my report in Group section of report. Now I want to show the static headers for cross tab.I have simply placed the text fields over cross tab in group section but it only appears once in whole group.For example if one group data expand to 3 pages my fields will be visible only on first page.I want to show it on every page over the cross tab.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing at what you mean by "static headers", and I am ASS-u-ME-ing you mean column names.

You shouldn't place static headers over an x-tab... if the data changes, the headers will be wrong.  Using the built in column name automatically traverses multiple pages.  If you need Custom headers, you can (usually) do that using a formula to filter the data, and then using the formula in place of the column.

You can get rows to traverse pages through the x-tab options.

If you're talking about a "title" for the x-tab, then I won't know.  Xtal did not include that common-sense item in this version.  The only way I can think of doing that is dorky:  Make a sub-report that only contains the xtab, put that in the group header, and place the group name over the open corner in the xtab, and set the options to repeat the group name on every page.  My best stab at titles.